# useEffect with setTimeout in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

countdown minus 2 every 1s. But if i clean up setTimeout, code run correctly. Can anyone explain?
My result: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NUE-nSLJbiY

```
    const tabs = ['posts', 'comments', 'albums'];
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    const [type, setType] = useState('posts');
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${type}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(post => {
                setPosts(post);
            })
    }, [type])
    useEffect(() => {
        document.title = title;
    })

    const [countdown, setCountdown] = useState(180);
    useEffect(() => {
        const id = setTimeout(() => {
            setCountdown(prev => prev - 1);
            console.log(countdown);
        }, 1000);
        // return () => {
        //     clearTimeout(id)
        // }
    })
```

Comment: So, you are saying that the countdown is decremented by 2 every time instead of one?

Comment: I guess setInterval and clearInterval might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I can use setInterval to build this clock. But i wanna try with setTimeout

Comment: your code is working here, decrementing minus 1 every second. or what do you want?

Comment: it minus 2 every second. i have up my video for that bug

Comment: then your bug might be somewhere else in your code. you need to post the context

Comment: exactly as you said. why other hooks create bug ?

Comment: try adding an empty list as a second parameter to useEffect hook:
`useEffect(() => { //main code }, []);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useEffect runs on every render. That means that when every value changes, a render happens, which then triggers another effect.

This is not what we want. There are several ways to control when side effects run.

We should always include the second parameter which accepts an array. We can optionally pass dependencies to useEffect in this array.

If you want to change countdown just after its value update, you should add dependencies to useEffect like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        const id = setTimeout(() => {
            setCountdown(prev => prev - 1);
            console.log(countdown);
        }, 1000);
        // return () => {
        //     clearTimeout(id)
        // }
    }, [countdown])
```

Above code runs on the first render and any time countdown value changes. In fact when the countdown decreases the top useEffect triger too.

```
  useEffect(() => {
        document.title = title;
    }) //has no dependency
```

then the document title were change which cause another render. so you are in a loop which cause decrement 2 for value of countdown.